# Jekyll pagination links

Tags: pagination, jekyll

I just updated Jekyll to 3.0.1, and now my pagination links are broken. I am using the code [from the Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/) to make links to each paginated page.

```
{% for page in (1..paginator.total_pages) %}
    {% if page == paginator.page %}
      <em>{{ page }}</em>
    {% elsif page == 1 %}
      <a href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path | prepend: site.baseurl | replace: '//', '/' }}">{{ page }}</a>
    {% else %}
      <a href="{{ site.paginate_path | prepend: site.baseurl | replace: '//', '/' | replace: ':num', page }}">{{ page }}</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

However, for the else case, the URLs it produces are not correct. For example, if I am on page 3 the link to page 4 is `example.com/page3/page4` (which doesn't exist) instead of `example.com/page4`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that with the baseurl set to `""`, it was appending the new page number to the existing URL. The solution was to prepend `/`:

```
{{ site.paginate_path | prepend: '/' | prepend: site.baseurl | replace: ':num', page | replace: '//', '/' }}
```

If the baseurl starts with a backslash, the replacement filter will take care of this.